# Plotly.js shift graph on x-axis by offset programmatically

Tags: position, scatter, plotly.js

I'm rendering a '`scattergl`' graph.

In my app there's the ability to switch between

- data from a specific time frame,
- or to show live data (updating each second).

For live view I'm using `extendTraces` to push new points every second.

In the live view I would like to change the x position of my graph, so the graph kind of "moves" through the screen having the new points always appear in the same spot.
Right now it is autoscaling, I don't want that when data is being streamed but I don't know how to set the frame or position or sth to achieve my goal.

This is now with the autoscaling:
[image: I get this]

This is opticallz what I want, + have all new points appear at the same spot, having old data being shifted to the left:
[image: This is what I want]

Also when switching from fixed time frame to live view I'd like to then "jump" to the updating data because when in live mode I'm not interested in the "big picture". I may like to zoom out manually, or pan back etc. but on switch it should "zoom" by my code to the new updating points.

I seem to use wrong search terms. Maybe someone knows the correct configuration option to pass ?

how I extend:

```
Plotly.extendTraces(nativeElement, {x, y}, numbers, maxPoints);
```

this is part of my data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "scatter",
      "x": [
        "2020-11-18T09:52:58.000Z",
        "2020-11-18T09:52:59.000Z",
        "2020-11-18T09:53:00.000Z",
        "2020-11-18T09:53:01.000Z"
      ],
      "y": [
        4.637524903199999,
        4.635876884400001,
        4.6342288656,
        4.635876884400001
      ],
      "time": [],
      "mode": "lines",
      "marker": {
        "size": 5
      },
      "domain": {
        "x": [
          0.25,
          0.75
        ],
        "y": [
          0.25,
          0.75
        ]
      },
      "showlegend": true,
      "name": "Euro/time\r\n<Beleuchtung 1>",
      "stackgroup": "one",
      "fill": "tonexty",
      "line": {
        "color": "rgba(230,230,77,1)",
        "width": 1,
        "dash": "solid"
      },
    },
  ],
  "layout": {
    "margin": {
      "l": 50,
      "r": 50,
      "t": 5,
      "b": 50
    },
    "autosize": true,
    "showlegend": false,
    "hovermode": "closest",
    "legend": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 1,
      "traceorder": "normal",
      "font": {
        "family": "sans-serif",
        "size": 10,
        "color": "#000"
      },
      "bgcolor": "#E2E2E255",
      "bordercolor": "#FFFFFF",
      "borderwidth": 2,
      "orientation": "h"
    },
    "title": null,
    "xaxis": {
      "tickfont": {
        "color": "#333",
        "size": 8
      },
      "title": null,
      "titlefont": {
        "color": "rgb(148, 103, 189)",
        "size": 10
      },
      "nticks": 20,
      "domain": [
        0.01,
        0.99
      ],
      "tickformatstops": [
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            null,
            1000
          ],
          "value": "%H:%M:%S.%L"
        },
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            1000,
            60000
          ],
          "value": "%H:%M:%S"
        },
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            60000,
            86400000
          ],
          "value": "%d.%m. %H:%M"
        },
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            86400000,
            604800000
          ],
          "value": "%d.%m.%y"
        },
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            604800000,
            "M1"
          ],
          "value": "%d.%m.%y"
        },
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            "M1",
            "M12"
          ],
          "value": "%b '%y"
        },
        {
          "dtickrange": [
            "M12",
            null
          ],
          "value": "%Y Y"
        }
      ]
    },
    "yaxis": {
      "tickfont": {
        "color": "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        "size": 8
      },
      "title": "Geld [T€/year]",
      "titlefont": {
        "color": "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        "size": 10
      },
      "side": "left",
      "domain": [
        0.05,
        0.95
      ],
      "showgrid": true,
      "ticks": "",
      "showticklabels": true,
      "position": 0
    },
    "hoverlabel": {
      "font": {
        "size": 10
      },
      "bgcolor": "#FFF",
      "namelength": -1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a range value inside x-axis layout property.

```
layout = {
    xaxis: {
        autorange: false,
        range: ['2016-07-01', '2016-12-31']
   },
   .....
};
```

https://plotly.com/javascript/time-series/#manually-set-range